# Is infrastructure management services same as DevOps?

Tags: devops, infrastructure

I am enrolled in Infrastructure management services(IMS), but I have less understanding of the domain. Is it same as the DevOps, if not what is IMS?

Comment: This isn't really a question suitable for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

No. IMS is tool (Ops tool). DevOps is combination of tools, process and culture.

Answer (score 0):

No , Not at all , although the roles and responsibilities cannot be defined , but devops has a broader role and has to be an intermediate between developer and operations engineer . Infra services are handled by infrastructure engineers who have better role in managing and creating IT infrastructure for a company . They have no idea about the software development and if there is a code error or config error , they could not find and correct the error , but a devops knows whole about the code as well as the deployment of that code in the infrastructure of that company . so it has a broader role . I have work closely with both of them but i never had an opportunity to be in any of the roles , so my answer might be partially correct . However , these both are just job titles which look out for nearly same kind of skill sets with a minor difference .